# How do I add an installed program to my PATH so I can run it from the command line?

Tags: environment-variables, path

I installed `jsx` using `npm`:

```
npm install -g jsx
```

Now it installed `jsx` in this path:

```
/node_modules/lib/node_modules/jsx/bin
```

In the `bin`, I'm having `jsx`. Now if type `./jsx`, it works fine as expected. But I need this compiler to get executed on a single command like `jsx`, I tried this:

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

Added these:

```
####path for jsx
JSX_HOME=~/node_modules/lib/node_modules/jsx/bin
export JSX_HOME
PATH=$JSX_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

I should be able to run `jsx` like:

```
~jsx --run hello.jsx~
```

for that I should be able to set a path for `jsx` command.

PS: `./jsx` inside the path works fine.

After reading the comments

I tried this

```
####path for jsx
    JSX_HOME=~/node_modules/lib/node_modules/jsx
    export JSX_HOME
    PATH=$JSX_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Result: Not working

I tried this as well

```
####path for jsx
    JSX_HOME=~/node_modules/lib/node_modules/jsx/bin
    export JSX_HOME
    PATH=$JSX_HOME:$PATH
```

Result: Not working

Comment: You seem to have a double `/bin` in there: you are adding `~/node_modules/lib/node_modules/jsx/bin/bin` to the `$PATH`. IS that the problem?

Comment: Did you re-login or source `~/.bashrc` after your changes?

Comment: Please verify your `JSX_HOME` path. `$JSX_HOME=~/node_modules/lib/node_modules/jsx/bin` and again you are suffixing /bin to it in the `PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As folks already noted, put the `/bin` only in `JSX_HOME` or `PATH`, not both.  Also, in `.bashrc`, it appears you have a tilde at the beginning of `JSX_HOME`.  Since there wasn't one on the install path you listed, try removing that.

Comment: Yes, problem with the tild symbol. You made my day :)

Comment: Glad to hear it! :)